# Selection sort sorting incorrectly

Tags: c, gcc

I was writing a selection sort, and it's not sorting properly, sometimes it works, but most of the time there is one or two numbers out of place. It's supposed to print an array of numbers, sort those numbers, then print them again. **It works in debug mode, but whenever I run it regularly, that's when the problems start happening.**

Note: In case your wondering why there's a while loop at the beginning that's because I'll be working on repeating it later.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

int print(int array[4]);

int main(void)
{

    bool loop = true;
    //main loop
    while (loop)
    {
        //array
        int array[5];

        //assign numbers
        int seconds= time(NULL);
        printf("%d\n", seconds);
        srand(seconds);
        for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            //random number between 0 and 5
            int r = rand();
            array[i] = r % 6;
        }
        //print numbers
        for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", array[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        //sort 
        int temp;
        for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            //set minimum
            int min = array[i];
            //check minimum value
            for(int j = i + 1; j <= 4; j++)
            {
                if(min > array[j])
                {
                    min = array[j];
                    temp = j;
                }
            }

            //swap minimum values
            int first = array[i];
            array[i] = min;
            array[temp] = first;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", array[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

int print(int array[4])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Output:

```
1584216938
3 5 1 4 1 
1 1 3 3 4
```

Comment: Your `swap` operation should sit inside the inner loop - instead of `temp = j;` statement.

Comment: OT: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 4, 5. 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `#define` statement or `enum` statement to give those magic numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: Swapping after the loop is okay -- selection sort finds the minimum values of the remaining array, then swaps once. But `temp` may be uninitialized or it may have an old value. Make `temp` local to the outer loop and initialize it to `temp = i`.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: OT: regarding: `int seconds= time(NULL);
        printf("%d\n", seconds);
        srand(seconds);`  This results in two compiler warnings.  Suggest: `unsigned seconds = (unsigned)time(NULL);
        printf("time: %u\n", seconds);
        srand(seconds);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the outer `for` loop you set the initial minimum value `int min = array[i];` but you forget to set the initial minimum value index (stored in `temp`).

This leads to unexpected behaviour in case the condition `if(min > array[j])` is not met in the inner `for` loop.

The fix is trivial:

```
        //set minimum
        int min = array[i];
        temp = i; // <---------
```